# Undo file deletion caused by git filter-branch

Tags: git, github

I recently needed to purge my git repo of sensitive data and used git filter-branch to do so (https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

However, I accidentally did a git pull afterwards, which deleted my files locally.

Is there any way to recover those files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git reflog` to show a history of where `HEAD` has been. One of the lines should describe your `git pull`; checkout the commit that is right after that in the log (and thus before it chronologically). Then you can tag it, branch it, or whatever to keep it preserved locally.